# Obtaining Depth Information of Facial Points Using Kinect

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect, face-recognition, depth

I am currently tracking a face using Microsoft's SDK and can detect 121 points on a face. I can get the co-ordinates of the points in the following manor:

```
            if (!this.lastFaceTrackSucceeded || this.skeletonTrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                return;

            var faceModelPts = new List<Point>();
            var faceModel = new List<FaceModelTriangle>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.facePoints.Count; i++)
            {
                faceModelPts.Add(new Point(this.facePoints[i].X + 0.5f, this.facePoints[i].Y + 0.5f));
                FaceDataPoints.XPointInfo[i] = this.facePoints[i].X;
                FaceDataPoints.YPointInfo[i] = this.facePoints[i].Y;
            }
```

But these points appear to be the co-ordinates for the colour image. How do I go about getting the respective depth information about each of these pixels. Such as point "20" on the users face?

Comment: Look through the FaceTracking project for "DepthToColor".  The tracker is mapping those coordinates somewhere -- I found several references but did not trace back the exact location.  You may be able to find the point in which the depth is mapped to the color.

Comment: I have found a couple in "FaceTracker.cs", They are under DepthToColorCallBack. Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: Yes.  This function shifts the depth points to match the color image.  Modifying the code and removing these *may* give the raw depth points.  I've not tried this, so I can't say for sure.  If time allows I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

"GetProjected3DShape" shape holds 2D coordinates used by the face tracking basics

To obtain the depth information use "Get3DShape"

comparison of the 2

```
        private EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, PointF> ColourPoints;

        private EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, Vector3DF> DepthPoints;
```

Depth points hold the information for the X,Y and Z co-ordinates for each of the facial points